# PHP session variables interchanged with local variables?

Tags: php, session, variables, local

I've encountered a very odd issue in regards to session variables and local variables in php.

I'm trying to figure out if I am not understanding something about sessions in php or if this is an issue with the php version my host is using.

Here is a very simple code to demonstrate the weird issue:

```
session_start();  
var_dump($kenny);  
var_dump($_SESSION['kenny']);  
$_SESSION['kenny']='def';  
var_dump($kenny);  
var_dump($_SESSION['kenny']);  
$kenny = 'abc';  
var_dump($kenny);  
var_dump($_SESSION['kenny']);
```

The first time I run the code, I get the following results (as one would expect):

```
NULL NULL NULL string(3) "def" string(3) "abc" string(3) "def"
```

I run it a second time (without closing my browser, of course), I get this now!

```
string(3) "def" string(3) "def" string(3) "def" string(3) "def" string(3) "abc" string(3) "abc"
```

I run it a 3rd, 4th, 5th time and so on, I get this!!!

```
string(3) "abc" string(3) "abc" string(3) "def" string(3) "def" string(3) "abc" string(3) "abc"
```

It looks to me like the session variable 'kenny' and local variable $kenny become aliases to one and the other after running the script more than once.  hmm... I really don't think this is how session variables and local variables work in php.  Please correct me if I'm missing something here.

My web host is running php 5.2.2.  When I try this exact same code on other hosts running php 5.2.1, 5.2.14 and 5.3.1, they always give me what I expect:

**1st time**:

```
NULL NULL NULL string(3) "def" string(3) "abc" string(3) "def"
```

**thereafter**:

```
NULL string(3) "def" NULL string(3) "def" string(3) "abc" string(3) "def"
```

I checked the change log on php.net and didn't find anything that I can relate to that may address this issue.  But like I mentioned, an earlier build (5.2.1) works ok, so that's very puzzling to me.

If anyone runs any other version of php 5.2.x, please give it a try and let me know if you see the same issue. Or if anyone has any insight into the issue, I'd really appreciate any feedback.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) directive is on. It doesn't say it on that page that `$_SESSION` variables are included, but it says [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php):

> If `register_globals` is enabled, then
>   the global variables and the
>   `$_SESSION` entries will automatically
>   reference the same values which were
>   registered in the prior session
>   instance. However, if the variable is
>   registered by `$_SESSION` then the
>   global variable is available since the
>   next request.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That page explained everything for me!  I always had register_globals off and assumed it'd be off after uploading it to the server (bad assumption on my part).  That's exactly the issue.  I hope others can be helped by this answer!