# Why does assigning to a local variable overwrite part of $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP session variables interchanged with local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779971/php-session-variables-interchanged-with-local-variables)

Well, I just found a "bug" in PHP, it just mess up $_SESSION and common variables!

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["test"] = 123;
$test = 456;

echo $_SESSION["test"];
```

for some reason, the output of this snippet is 456! is it ok or is just a php bug?

Comment: You probably have `register_globals` on, upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP session variables interchanged with local variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779971/php-session-variables-interchanged-with-local-variables) ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097068/php-session-variables-randomly-get-overwritten?rq=1 ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411134/php-array-stored-in-session-is-set-to-null-if-we-initialise-a-array-with-same-wi?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943608/asigning-value-to-a-variable-changes-session-too?rq=1

Comment: Checkout this link It will help you to understand concept of [register_globals ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php